# Does ORDER BY on a clustered key affect performance?

Tags: sql-server, performance, clustered-index, order-by

Say I have a table clustered on *PrimaryKey*, and in all cases I want my results to be ordered by *PrimaryKey*, so I additionally always `ORDER BY PrimaryKey` in all queries.

Does this `ORDER BY` affect performance in any way or is it ignored by the profiler as the rows are already in this order?

I am using a SQL Server 2005 database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It almost certainly will affect performance.**

If you just do a query like

```
Select *
From Table
Order by PrimaryKey
```

It likely won't affect anything at all.

Bear in mind, though, that this only determines the order of the rows at the leaf level of the clustered index.  If you do `JOIN`s, or use other indexes that avoid key lookups, then the `ORDER BY` will generate additional work.

If every index and every table that you will ever `JOIN` or reference when querying this table are all ordered by the same key (in the same direction) then it probably won't impact performance.  Outside that very limited scenario, you will see a hit.

Only use `ORDER BY` when the order of the results actually matters.  In my experience it's seldom necessary.

Comment: In this case I'm grabbing rows for presentation so order matters and I'm usually only JOINING tables which are all clustered on the same primary/foreign key. Is the `ORDER BY` additional work even when I join two tables clustered in the same exact manner?

Comment: @BenBrocka - it might be.  There's really no general rule for this.  If the intermediate result sets (i.e. once the tables are joined) needs to be reordered, that's work as well.  It's unlikely that there won't be any sorting involved at all.

Comment: @BenBrocka - If you already have a useful index in the order requested already then SQL Server will probably be more likely to consider order preserving operators (e.g. avoiding hash joins and aggregates) unless statistics lead it to believe it will be cheaper not to.

Answer (score 4):

For a complex query, SQL Server may decide that it needs to sort portions of data in your query, and may even require multiple sort operators based on which indexes are available and the complexity of your query.

These sorts can definitely impact the performance of your query especially if you are working with large tables, and in some cases you'll find that adding an Order By statement will significantly change the execution plan SQL Server generates for your query.

If you're interested in seeing the impact of Sorting the queries you're tuning, run the Actual Plan with SQL Sentry Plan Explorer (free) or using SSMS with "Include Actual Execution Plan" turned on and look at the Ordered Indicator by hovering over the individual data steps in the plan.  In Plan Explorer you can also look at the Ordered column in the Plan Tree or Top Operations view.

For something as simple as:

```
Select * 
From Table 
Order by PrimaryKey
```

You should find that while the Order By doesn't seem to change the query plan of your query, that the Ordered indicator in the execution plan does change from False to True when you add the Order By.

You'll may have heard that ["the order of the results returned from a SELECT statement cannot be guaranteed without an ORDER BY clause"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms191475%28v=sql.90%29); One reason for this is a feature of the [Enterprise Edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/boduff/why-should-i-use-sql-enterprise-edition) of SQL Server that allows SQL Server to piggyback one table scan on top of another, sometimes called a "Merry-go-round" scan and also called ["Advanced Scanning"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms191475%28v=sql.90%29).

For further research, I highly recommend both of the following books which are currently available as free ebooks from RedGate:

- [SQL Server Execution Plans By Grant Fritchey](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-monitor/entrypage/execution-plans)
- [Inside the SQL Server Query Optimizer By Benjamin Nevarez](https://www.red-gate.com/library/inside-the-sql-server-query-optimizer)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Look at the query plan for both queries, you will see that the "order by" clause will result in a sort of the data that is returned by the remainder of the query (which should be in memory, but could be paged if memory insufficient). The time that sort takes is related to the amount of data (it has to walk it at least once) and how well ordered the data already is (it may be correctly ordered if you are sorting on an indexed column, or data joined  on a indexed column)